# Why does drawing a qiskit quantum circuit look different when I run a jupyter notebook locally

Tags: jupyter-notebook, quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm using the [qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/representing-qubit-states.html), and it creates a `QuantumCircuit` and then draws the circuit, and it looks like this:
[image: visualization of quantum circuit from qiskit textbook]

I see the same result when running the textbook as a jupyter notebook in [IBM's quantum lab](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab).

However, when I download the textbook as a jupyter notebook and run it myself locally, it looks like this:
[image: visualization of quantum circuit from locally hosted jupyter notebook]

I don't like this very much, and I think I am missing something simple. The code that is running is exactly the same. I am using MacOS 11.4 (Big Sur). The following code is sufficient to show a difference when I run it online vs. locally:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)  # Create a quantum circuit with one qubit
initial_state = [0,1]   # Define initial_state as |1>
qc.initialize(initial_state, 0) # Apply initialisation operation to the 0th qubit
qc.draw()  # Let's view our circuit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Qiskit has multiple drawers. Those are:

- `text`
- `mpl`
- `latex`
- `latex_source`.

The drawer you see in the IBM Quantum Lab is the one based on Matplotlib. You can get the same output by `qc.draw('mpl')`.

To set a default, you can change (or create if does not exist) the file `~/.qiskit/settings.conf`) with the entry `circuit_drawer = mpl`.